# Error while trying to query data from SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, development, caml-query

I am building a visual web part application with c# and i need to query items from my list, but i have to add some conditionals.

I am successfully querying ID and Title but I need another conditional to show items only if they are created earlier than example 5 May 2017.

I am trying the following query but it is not working and it shows me an error?

why?

please help me!

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <And>
     <Lt>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        <Value Type='Counter'>10</Value>
     </Lt>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name='Title' />
           <Value Type='Text'>text</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Leq>
           <FieldRef Name='Created' />
           <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-05-05T17:01:50Z</Value>
        </Leq>
  </And>
 </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error in your query at this section, where you forget to add **And**

```
<And>
   <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='Title' />
       <Value Type='Text'>text</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Leq>
       <FieldRef Name='Created' />
       <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-05-05T17:01:50Z</Value>
    </Leq>
</And>
```

the final one should looks like

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Lt>
    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
    <Value Type='Counter'>10</Value>
    </Lt>
         <And>
   <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='Title' />
       <Value Type='Text'>text</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Leq>
       <FieldRef Name='Created' />
       <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-05-05T17:01:50Z</Value>
    </Leq>
   </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

My suggestion is to build your query with a [CAML Query builder like (U2U)](https://www.u2u.be/software) to avoid the syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Try it as below:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' />
                <Value Type='Counter'>10</Value>
        </Lt>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                       <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                       <Value Type='Text'>text</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Leq>
                       <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                       <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-05-05T17:01:50Z</Value>
            </Leq>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```